# What to use instead of exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception

I'm using c++ and i'm in a really deeply nested set of functions and a special case has occurred and I would like to exit to the top level.

Now I hear c++ exceptions are deprecated now so what should I use instead in this case?

So what i'm really asking is, are `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` OK in c++ code?

Comment: I would say it's the other way around, that `setjmp`/`longjmp` are deprecated in C++ (no stack unwinding, so destructors not called for objects on the stack), in favor of exceptions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `setjmp`/`longjmp` aren't formally deprecated; they're there for C compatibility reasons, and will remain.  But you still shouldn't use them in C++.  (Even in C, their use can be problematic.)

Comment: If you didn't want to use exceptions, you could always go back to the winapi/Qt approach of returning error/success codes from every function call. I find that style of code awfully verbose and issue-prone. Nothing wrong with using exceptions. They're not going to go away or be deprecated.

Comment: Exceptions are not deprecated, exception specifications are. They were never honoured by most compilers anyway. So, effectively, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible I would avoid using `setjmp/longjmp`, as most C stuff, in C++ code. For what concerns C++ exceptions, as far as I know, they are *not* deprecated. Indeed, I think it would be very hard to deprecate such a pervasive feature without severely hindering backwards compatibility. It's possible that you have heard that (some form of) exception *specifications*, <s>a feature of the recent C++11 standard that was not present in the previous version of the language,</s> has been deprecated during the approval process (see, e.g., [this post](http://herbsutter.com/2010/03/13/trip-report-march-2010-iso-c-standards-meeting/) on Herb Sutter's blog).

This said, exceptions in C++ are not easy to use well. C++ has lots of features, and sometimes they interplay in very complex ways. Some necessary (but not sufficient) advices are:

- Derive your exceptions from `std::exception`;
- Manage your resources via RAII;
- Catch by reference, not by value or by pointer.

But the best advice is: understand exactly how exceptions work - precanned advices do not work well. At the purpose, you might read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38449/C-Exceptions-Pros-and-Cons#3_2), [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/exceptions.html), [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X) and [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) about how to use exceptions and RAII. Especially "More Effective C++" has a whole chapter dedicated to exceptions, exposing some intricate consequences of apparently simple snippets of code. It raises your overall awareness of the language.

Comment: Exception specifications **were** present in the previous standard. The old form, `throw(type, type2, type3)` is now called a _dynamic-exception-specification_ and is deprecated. The new form, using `noexcept`, is **not** deprecated

Answer (score 11):

C++ exceptions are **not** deprecated only exceptions specifications are deprecated.
There is a difference between the two. You should use RAII and exceptions.

Comment: only **dynamic** exception specifications are deprecated. `noexcept(true)` and `noexcept(false)` are not deprecated

Comment: I'd almost go as far as to say if you're using C++ and you're not using RAII, you're missing out on one of the most important language benefits.